# How to create same link for mobile and desktop

Tags: magento-1.7, htaccess

I wan to create same link for my mobile and desktop website in magento. So my question is that when i used htaccess then it will redirect by check device,but url changed in url bar, so how can i prevent this .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I believe having responsive design will do the magic for you.

Comment: Can you post .htaccess content? Need more info about your question

Answer (score 1):

With a responsive Magento theme such as the default rwd (responsive web design) theme in Magento CE1.9 the shop url is the same for all devices.

The responsive css adapts the frontend creating variable sized webpages for desktop, mobile, tablets etc.